# Going in camera instantly when the user load the view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I would like to create a ViewController, and when the user loads it, he's automatically redirected to camera.
I know how to go in camera when the user press a button, but not when he doesn't do anything.
For example, when you load snapchat app, you're automatically in the camera to take a picture, I would like to perform that.

Any ideas ? Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert your code in the method of `viewDidLoad`. What that does is, as soon as the view loaded, whatever is in that method gets called.

Take a look at this page: [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/)

Comment: Just before testing, do you think I should go in Objective-C ? I want to customize the camera (add buttons, add a picture filter fonction...), and I saw the only one module which permits that is only available on O-C...

Comment: Well, you can use both if you want. Here is a video tutorial of adding a picture filter: http://www.swiftvideotutorials.com/core-image-filters-on-ios

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think i'll stay in swift.
I follow this tutorial : http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/take-photo-tutorial-ios8-swift which permit me to access camera when I press on a button. You told me to put it in `viewDidLoad`, but how ?
Should I call the `takePhoto()` function in the `viewDidLoad()` function ?

Comment: Ok I just tested it by myself and it works. Thank's very much !
here's my code:

`class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    
    
    @IBOutlet var pictureImageView: UIImageView!
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
        
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
}`

Comment: Glad to hear it works!

Comment: Swift 4.2 
imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

imagePicker.delegate = self

imagePicker.sourceType = .camera

present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)